# WPF MVVM with multiple nested UserControls/Models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

For last two years I started diving into programming with C#. After reading and watching tutorials I tried to make my own app but I'm stuck at the point to get everything glued together.

I have a MainWindow with a TabControl. The first tab is an Overview and works fine with my Model and ViewModel (BaseViewModel implemented with RaisePropertyChanged() calls).
The next tabs are more or less independent to eachother but they have multiple UserControls in there.
The UserControls are not only plain collections of TextBoxes and Buttons but also have (editable) ComboBoxes and ListViews which filled up by other Models.

XAML Pseudo-code:

```
<MainWindow>
<Grid>
<TabControl>
<TabItem1> Overview ViewModel </TabItem1>
<TabItem2> UserControl1 </TabItem2>
<TabItem3> UserControl2 </TabItem3>
... etc
</TabControl>
</Grid>
</MainWindow>
```

A UserControl can occur at least once or multiple times inside a TabItem (via Button Command, add/remove to/from ObservableCollection). Inside that UserControl a ListView (or another approach) can be filled with data bound to an underlying model.

I already tried to implement my UserControls with registered dependencies but I don't see how I could register a ListView inside the UserControl to be able to bind to it. So I switched to another approach of having a separate ViewModel for each "parent UserControl". At this point I'm also stuck because I cannot be sure the "child UserControls" or models are a subset of the parent UserControl.

So somehow I'm doing something wrong but I don't see what exactly.

I hope someone can provide some hints.

---

EDIT:
I've put an overview on how my data should be represented.

[General Overview for Models in UserControls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQpsA.png)

Any ideas on how to implement those structures are welcome.

Comment: "*separate ViewModel for each ... UserControl"* is however the wrong approach. The UserControls in the TabItems should get their view model by property value inheritance of the DataContext property. This means the TabControl's ItemsSource property should be bound to a collection of data items, where each item represents the data set for a TabItem. The UserControls would be instantiated by appropriate DataTemplates.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you! I think I will need to read more and to refract my code.